# Linux and GTK: GtkFileSelection vs. GtkFileChooserDialog

Tags: linux, user-interface, dialog, gtk

In GTK, the GtkFileSelection (via gtk_file_selection_new) and the GtkFileChooserDialog (via gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new) look like they're intended for the same purpose but with different appearances.

Is there any reason I should prefer one over the other or is it just a matter of picking the one that is most visually appealing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`GtkFileSelection`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkFileSelection.html) is deprecated in the current stable version.  You should use [`GtkFileChooserDialog`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkFileChooserDialog.html).

Comment: Good answer.  The tutorial is a bit misleading since it still references GtkFileSelection ( http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk-tutorial/2.23/x1207.html )